# ListView Sort not setting SortExpression and SortDirection

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, sorting

I'm working on a `ListView` and am getting that feeling that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong when it comes to implementing sorting. Rather than being able to depend on the values of `List1.SortExpression` and `List1.SortDirection`, I'm resorting to hidden fields because `List1.SortExpression` is always blank and `List1.SortDirection` is always `SortDirection.Ascending`.

On my .aspx page: (edited out irrelevant code)

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnSortExpression" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnSortDirection" />

<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="List1"  
    OnItemCommand="List1_ItemCommand"
    OnSorting="List1_Sorting">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="BtnCompanyCode" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="CompanyCode" Text="Company Code" /></th>
        ... more columns ...
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
```

In my Code Behind:

```
protected void List1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // empty for now
}

protected void List1_Sorting(object sender, ListViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    SortDirection sortDirection;
    String sortExpression = e.SortExpression;   // how we need to do it in Sorting

    if (hdnSortExpression.Value.ToLower() == sortExpression.ToLower())
        sortDirection = hdnSortDirection.Value == SortDirection.Ascending.ToString() ? SortDirection.Descending : SortDirection.Ascending;
    else
        sortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;

    DoSortList(sortExpression, sortDirection);  // this sets column headings' sort indicator arrows
    List1_BindData(sortExpression, sortDirection);  // sets DataSource and calls DataBind()

    // the hacky part: setting hidden fields to store sortExpression and sortDirection
    hdnEligibilitySortExpression.Value = sortExpression;
    hdnEligibilitySortDirection.Value = sortDirection.ToString();
}

private void List1_BindData(String sortExpression, SortDirection sortDirection)
{
    List<SomeEntity> list = null;

    list = SomeEntity.GetBySsn(_ssn).ToList();  // methods generated by an ORM pointing to an Oracle database

    switch (sortExpression.ToLower())
    {
        case "CompanyCode":
        if (sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
            List1.DataSource = list.OrderBy(o => o.CompanyCode);
        else
            List1.DataSource = list.OrderByDescending(o => o.CompanyCode);
        break;

        ... other cases ...
    }

    List1.DataBind();
}
```

It works -- each column gets sorted correctly, clicking the same column reverses sort direction, but I have to conclude that I've wired things up incorrectly because I cannot depend on the `SortDirection` and `SortExpression` properties. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's just how it works. I've heard somewhere if you bind the `ListView` using the Data Source Control then the sorting will work as you are expecting, but not if you manually bind the datasource. But I can't confirm that.

Comment: @Dave interesting. I suppose I wouldn't mind if SortExpression and SortDirection weren't read only properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.sortdirection.aspx).
You will notice that the DataSource is a SqlDataSource. This is one of the DataSource types that .Net understands how to sort. Others, not so much.

Here's another [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa88ktts%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that specifies the DataSource types:

> The data source controls that provide built-in support for sorting are the LinqDataSource, ObjectDataSource, SqlDataSource, and AccessDataSource controls.

Comment: Mine is not one of those. I manually sort and bind my data. See my edit, above.

Comment: Well then, your answer from .Net, as far as I can tell, is "Too bad." In fact, your hidden field method is exactly the technique used by the team at my previous job. I took some time to try to use SorExpression and SortDirection and came to the conclusion that they are not an option.

Comment: Posterity: I have accepted this answer as correct because it answers the question I've posed. "What am I doing wrong?" Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use e.SortDirection can you pull it off the ListView like List1.SortDirection and List1.SortExpression?

Comment: I'll double-check, (sometimes the obvious is in plain sight...) but the point of my question is that List1.SortDirection and List1.SortExpression never change from Ascending and "", respectively.

Comment: Oh gotcha, I thought that from the event the state was incorrect and maybe on the control it would be.